# multiple video cards on windows 7 64bit

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have two nividia 9500 cards in two seperate PCIe 16x slots BUT one of the cards is always disabled by windows (code 43 error) so I am unable to run 4 monitors.  Both cards are good as has been verified and both PCIE slots work individually.  Any thoughts on what is going on?

Comment: Is it the card or the slot that's disabled?

Comment: 2+ Nvidia cards in a non-SLI configuration are probably more trouble than they're worth, look at finding a 2nd identical card to save you some headaches.

Answer (score 2):

I have come up against code 43 twice in a similar situation with two Nvidia cards (non SLI), and two different solutions helped me.

The first time, it was driver related, simply "cycling" it by uninstalling the device (Go to device manager, right click and do uninstall device) then I did scan for new hardware and it worked.

The second time, the cycling trick didn't work, but I simply installed the [latest version of the drivers](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index5.aspx?lang=en-us), then a reboot made it magically work.